# Botframework V4: Reset Bot in Messenger

Tags: c#, botframework, messenger

Hello i have recently published my bot to azure and deployed it to messenger for testing purposes. The first part of the bot ask the user for name and age. How can i reset the whole conversation when the user type "reset"? Like delete all the data saved in memory storage. I am using C# and i save the user data to in-memory storage.

```
     IStorage dataStore = new MemoryStorage();          
     var conversationState = new ConversationState(dataStore);
     options.State.Add(conversationState);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I would echo what @JJ_Wailes has said about using the `MemoryStorage` provider in a production bot: just don't.

That said, to answer your question directly, yes you can delete all state for a given `BotState` (e.g. `ConversationState`, `UserState`, etc) using [the `DeleteAsync` API](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/5af86286f79f08c23fc330bf9193e4c2f0732562/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/BotState.cs#L128).

Comment: Hello sir thank you for your advice on the memory storage i am just testing it for now. I will change it to a proper database storage when the project is finish. I think this answer might work i can't test it right now since I am outside. I'll test it as soon as i can thank you.

Comment: May I ask sir how can i use this command? For example when a user type "botReset".

Comment: You would be injecting the `BotState` subclass (e.g. `ConversationState`) into your `IBot` and then, when you receive the command you want to handle, call it's `DeleteAsync` method.

Comment: Sir how do you put a messenger location quick reply to a prompt? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337406/put-messenger-quick-repy-to-a-prompt-botframework-v4-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Hihi!

In-memory data storage is intended for testing only. This storage is volatile and temporary. The data is cleared each time the bot is restarted. There is no need to 'delete' it, it deletes itself the second you restart the bot. That being said, to 'reset' a bot in the FB messenger channel, when you're on the https://www.messenger.com page, navigate to the gear icon in the upper right:

[image]

There will be an option to 'delete' the conversation. Click this, then go to the right side, where there's a list of people. Search for your bot's name once more, and the bot conversation will be started over.

[image]

and voila! Reset:

[image]

Comment: Hi sir thank you for your answer but i already did that and i even disabled and enabled again the messenger channel in azure but that did not work.